# C# DataGridView Column Order

Tags: c#

In my application, I have a `DataGridView` whose data source varies depending on the button you click.

For example, clicking 'Total Downloads' will be:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = totalDownloads();
```

Or the downloads per player

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = playerDownloads();
```

Each method obtains data via SQL query and returns a `dataTable` of this information.

However, with my following code:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource=getStats();
public DataTable getStats()
   {
        DataTable table1 = new DataTable("Totals");
        table1.Columns.Add("Park Name");
        table1.Columns.Add("Author");
        table1.Columns.Add("Total Downloads");
        table1.Columns[2].DataType = typeof(int);
        table1.Columns.Add("Rating (Max 5)");           
        table1.Columns[3].DataType = typeof(float);
        table1.Rows.Add(name,author,download, rating);
        }
        return table1;
    }
```

I expected to see the columns in the order: "Park Name" "Author" "Total Downloads" "Rating"
However, they come in "Downloads", "Park Name", "Author", "Rating"

I've read that adding `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;`
will fix this...however, this makes no difference to the order at all...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Is this a WinForms project or an Asp.net one?

If it's winforms you should be able to change the order the columns are displayed in by accessing your GridViews Columns DisplayIndex

```
    dataGridView1.Columns["Park Name"].DisplayIndex = 0; // or 1, 2, 3 etc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
Whilst this works...I am very curious at why they weren't appearing in the right order in the first place.
I've been using DataGridView a lot for a lot bigger projects but I've never experienced this before....

Comment: Yeah, it's interesting. I would have thought they'd default to the order that they're added in. Have you tried a complete restart / cleaning of the project? Just to be sure nothing is being cached.

Answer (score 11):

My simple solution to the columns being out of order is to add this loop that sets the `DisplayIndex` to the `Index`.

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in grid.Columns) {
    col.DisplayIndex = col.Index;
}
```

The `Index` is assigned to each column as they are added. I'm not sure why the `DisplayIndex` becomes out of order, but the above script will fix it.

This might work as well as a one-liner:

```
grid.Columns.foreach(c => c.DisplayIndex = c.Index);
```

Comment: This fixed my issue. Columns were dynamically sorted in a generated SQL query, but sometimes they would fall out of order but only on certain tables. The solution you posted worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

For me it did not the trick.
One more line needed:

```
entityDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

Regards!

Comment: If you are using a database then you will almost always want this be set to true.

Answer (score 5):

Try to play with the display index like this

```
 private void AdjustColumnOrder()
{
    customersDataGridView.Columns["Park Name"].DisplayIndex = 0;
    customersDataGridView.Columns["Author"].DisplayIndex = 1;
    customersDataGridView.Columns["Total Downloads"].DisplayIndex = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved with:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = null;
dataGridView.DataSource = MyDataTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be very helpful.

**Usage:** ColumnDisplayOrder("Park Name, Author, Total Downloads", myDataGridView);

```
    private void ColumnDisplayOrder(string columnList, DataGridView gridView)
    {
        var columnListArray = columnList.Split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < columnListArray.Length; i++)
        {
            var gridViewColumn = gridView.Columns[columnListArray[i].Trim()];
            if (gridViewColumn != null)
                gridViewColumn.DisplayIndex = i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is interesting. I'll have to try it sometime.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found the reason. It's due to the order of the class properties:

```
   public string Downloads { get; set; }
   public string ParkName { get; set; }
   public string Author { get; set; }
   public float Rating { get; set; }
```

gives you *Downloads, Park Name, Author, Rating*

If you rearrange them, the order should be like you'd expect it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with column order in datagrid, in my project data source was list of objects, through designer I added column in right order, but when I started application order was mixed. As I added binding on my properties from class I noticed that my properties are in wrong order in regard to column order in datagrid, so I added properties in class in same order like I added columns and I got correct order even if *AutoGenerateColumns* is set to *true*.